# How does the FBI seize websites if they cannot use the law?

Tags: government

After doing some research about websites that have been taken down like **Silk Road** I have been extremely curious about the procedure that the **FBI** does to take down a website from the Internet.

How do they do it **if the website is hosted in another country** for example? Do they just contact the hosting company and blackmail them? Does the FBI "hack" the websites they cannot seize?

My question applies for **both** Dark Web and Clear Web websites. I understand that is much easier for a government entity to just use the law for their purposes but that's not always possible...

[image]

Comment: They use the law.

Comment: Silk Road's security was a little shoddy, and the FBI exploited this to locate their servers and seize them.  See https://www.forbes.com/sites/katevinton/2014/09/08/the-feds-explain-how-they-seized-the-silk-road-servers/#72906560af68.

Comment: *" I understand that is much easier for a government entity to just use the law for their purposes but that's not always possible..."* - this is a broad claim you are making, essentially arguing that the FBI is working outside the law. Note that FBI cooperates with other agencies in the world to seize sites which are outside the US law. And it might not be necessary to seize the site but it might be sufficient to seize a domain name etc.and the registries often fall under US law.

Comment: @mti2935 thanks for that link, it was really helpful

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hacking a website to take it down is not effective; the target can simply regain control of their machine or restart the service somewhere else. The objective of the FBI is to make arrests and obtain convictions, not play whack-a-mole.

When the FBI targets a website and its operators there are a number of approaches that it can use, depending on the circumstances.

- For clear-web sites one simple approach is just to seize the domain name. When you type `badsite.com` into a web browser a system called DNS looks up the name in a distributed database and from that gets an IP address. The DNS database is [managed by a number of national and international authorities](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domain_name_registry), and most national authoritities will cooperate with legal requests from the FBI, possibly routed through INTERPOL or via a [Mutual Legal Assistance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mutual_legal_assistance_treaty) treaty. Of course there are some countries that won't cooperate, and this on its own doesn't help the FBI to arrest anyone.
- The FBI can use an IP address to find out where the physical servers are located. If that is in the US then they can simply go and [seize those servers as evidence, or use a subpoena](https://www.justice.gov/sites/default/files/criminal-ccips/legacy/2015/01/14/ssmanual2009.pdf). If it is outside the US then its back to INTERPOL or Mutual Legal Assistance.
- Servers on the "dark net" use [TOR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tor_(anonymity_network)) to bounce the packets around the Net a few times. This hides the IP addresses of both servers and clients, so the challenge for the FBI is to find out what the IP address of the target machine is. Once they have that they can proceed as normal. Getting the IP address generally means hacking the target machine via TOR, and then finding the IP address once inside.

If the DNS and servers are hosted in a country that won't play ball with the FBI, well that is just too bad. The FBI can carry on investigating of course, and if someone running the website ever travels to a country where the FBI can get them arrested then they will do so.

Comment: Thanks for the answer!

Answer (score 2):

The notice you use as an example is a domain name seizure notice - the FBI uses its jurisdiction with [ICANN](https://www.icann.org/) to [seize the domain from its owners](https://www.icann.org/en/system/files/files/guidance-domain-seizures-07mar12-en.pdf).

They can do this because ICANN isn’t immune to US authority - they are a US non-profit and thus fall under US jurisdiction.  Thus all domain names fall under US jurisdiction.

Comment: No, only for domains which are directly administered by ICANN (used to be the Big 7; .com, .edu etc. Now its bigger). National domains (.uk etc) are administed by national authorities. Short of de-registering an entire national domain ICANN can't force them to do anything.

Comment: @PaulJohnson that didnt seem to stop the FBI seizing all national domains for Backpage...  Plus Microsoft has used the same US-based legal process to seize national domains as well.  ICANN are also responsible for root DNS, so they can override DNS entries for domains at a lower level than the national registries have access to, which is how domain seizures happen.

Comment: No they can't. The root name servers just hand off queries to the top level domain servers, which in turn hand off queries to subdomains etc. So when you look for www.foo.bar.com the root server refers you on to the .com server, which refers you to the bar.com server, which refers you to the foo.bar.com server, which finally gives you the answer. All these servers can be in different countries. If they *happen* to be in the US then its easy. Otherwise its international diplomacy.

Comment: @PaulJohnson given Ive implemented a DNS server from scratch, I know how they work, and while your explanation is correct in a laymans high level way, root servers do a heck of a lot more and they can override everything below them in the hierarchy.

Comment: This answer is only answer to discuss ICANN and how it falls under US and only US jurisdiction.

Comment: ICANN only directly runs a handful of registries. The major generic TLDs are subject to US law, but that’s because they’re run by US-based registries (e.g. .com is run by Verisign).